# Is $\mathbb{Z_+}$ a baire space ? Yes/No

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{Z_+}$   a baire space  ? Yes/No

**My thinking** :   No

**My attempt**: I think $\mathbb{Z_+}$  is not a baire space because  each singleton in $\mathbb{Z_+}$ is closed and has empty interior in $\mathbb{Z}_+$.Let $(n)$  be an  enumeration  of the set $\mathbb{Z}_+$.Then $(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{n})^\circ=(\mathbb{Z_+})^{\circ}=\mathbb{Z_+}$

Edit :$\mathbb{Z_+}$ endowed with usual topology

Comment: A singleton has not empty interior.

Comment: why  ?@jjagmath.Im not getting

Comment: A singleton is open. So is equal to its interior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\Bbb{Z^+}$ induced the usual topology inherited as a euclidean subspace of $\Bbb{R}$

I think you want to prove $\Bbb{Z^+}$ is not a Baire space by showing it is not of second category in itself i.e you want to express $\Bbb{Z^+}$ as countable union of nowhere dense sets.

Each $\{n\}$ is closed but it's interior is non empty as it is open.

In fact only nowhere dense set is the trivial one (empty set), which is useless in this context.

---

Baire space means sequence of open dense sets has dense intersection.

Only dense subset of $\Bbb{Z^+} $ is $\Bbb{Z^+}$ itself.

Hence any sequence of open sets has intersection $\Bbb{Z}^+$ .

---

$\mathbb{Z_+}$ is a discrete space. Hence complete.

By Baire's theorem , it is a Baire space

Comment: okay that mean $\{n\}$ is both closed and open .Am i right ?